# Can't download .exe, stuck at 99% for all browsers

Tags: windows-xp, networking, download

I can't seem to *finish* downloading any .exe files. When the download starts, it will proceed as per normal except that it will be stuck once it hits 99%. I had noticed this problem since a *looong* time ago and it still persists today despite this post being already past 16 months old.

I've tried using Chrome, Safari, Opera, and Internet Explorer but they all have this behavior; Chrome screenshot:

[image]

and IE screenshot:

[image]

etc, etc. I've probably read [all the threads on Google](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=i%20cant%20download%20any%20files%20stuck%20at%2099) but **none** of the solution works.

What may be causing the problem?

## Details:

- I don't have Firewall or anti-virus installed.
- I'm using an administrator account.
- I'm on [Windows XP SP3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKLOa.png).
- There is [sufficient disk space for the downloads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXeAJ.png).
- I can download movies using .torrent files as per usual.
- I've tried downloading random stuff like:

  - [Php Storm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)
    http://download-cf.jetbrains.com/webide/PhpStorm-8.0.1.exe
  - [Adobe Air](http://get.adobe.com/air/)
    http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/win/download/13.0/AdobeAIRInstaller.exe
  - [Java](http://java.com)
    http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=88625
  - [uTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/)
    http://download-new.utorrent.com/endpoint/utorrent/os/windows/track/stable/
  - [IObit Uninstaller](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.html)
    http://software-files-a.cnet.com/s/software/13/62/42/33/iobituninstaller.exe?lop=link&ptype=3001&ontid=2096&siteId=4&edId=3&spi=9a859f165f04fd25527e8b8e28b8c166&pid=13624233&psid=75161625&token=1398695788_05f84ea4dde45c2451c694df0589279a&fileName=iobituninstaller.exe
  - [Allmyapps](http://allmyapps.com/)
    http://dde.storage.dmccint.com//51/178/ct1780051/e9a0b9b00b5c4499a43b3cd7b196dc25/Downloads/Prod/DDE1.3.8.9.140410.01/14-04-27-12.04.26.227/Allmyapps.exe?filename=Allmyapps_TSA12LG3M.exe

  , etc but they all have this behavior.

  From my tests, it seems to be only a problem with .exe files, although for some reason **I can still download certain .exe files**, for example:

  - [FireFox](http://getfirefox.com)
    https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/28.0/win32/en-GB/Firefox%20Setup%20Stub%2028.0.exe
  - [BlueStacks App Player](http://www.bluestacks.com/app-player.html)
    http://cdn.bluestacks.com/public/beta-1/BlueStacks-SplitInstaller_native.exe
  - [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org)
    https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/3.5.4/torbrowser-install-3.5.4_en-US.exe
  - [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/)
    http://www.rarlab.com/rar/wrar501.exe

---

Now, it's totally weird because if I download the [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) exe file using another computer and upload it directly to Google Docs, then try to download it from Google Docs using this computer, it works perfectly, even though that exact same file cannot be downloaded directly from the link http://download-cf.jetbrains.com/webide/PhpStorm-8.0.1.exe .

Comment: Do you have free space on the volume?

Comment: @DanD. yes I've got 88 GB of free space.

Comment: Why would "SmartScreen Filter" have checked the download before it finished? (Look at the bottom of the first image.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, exactly. that's odd.

Comment: From another machine download a copy of the Firefox [DownloadThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/) add-on and move its .xpi file to your machine and install it.

Comment: @Pacerier: Have you tried disabling it?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Yep the problem still persists (see update)

Comment: This happens with **all files**? addition to executables?

Comment: Have you tried disabling add ons and reset the browsers ?

Comment: Since you have no firewall or antivirus, maybe you've been infected with some malware and this is an odd side effect of that? It's a good idea to do regular scans anyway.

Comment: Have you tried saving to a different directory?

Comment: @Keltari, yepp doesn't work

Comment: try copying a file into your temporary internet folder and then moving it out.  what happens?

Comment: @Keltari, my %temp% points to C:\DOCUME~1\Owner\LOCALS~1\Temp . There's no problem copying files into it and then moving it out..

Comment: @TiagoƇ. Just executables from my tests so far.

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Defender / Windows Firewall / any built in anti-malware stuff enabled ?

Comment: @Lawrence, nope I don't have any of those. For example, when I try to open Windows Firewall, this is what I see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XxPte.png

Comment: Why do you keep using Windows XP after the official end of support on 8th April 2014?

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm. Irregardless, I'm stuck with an old system here.

Comment: Very good to know.

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm, yea http://gs.statcounter.com/press/less-than-a-week-to-go-and-xp-remains-worlds-second-most-popular-operating-system

Comment: @Pacerier Microsoft has also decided to release a update for Internet Explorer including a update for the Internet Explorer installed on Windows XP. This despite the official end of support.

Comment: Probably not related, but note that some executables might have been digitally signed. I cannot check if that's true for Firefox and the other examples you listed, but the only [reference in a comment](http://superuser.com/questions/563201/download-stops-at-99-and-gives-error#comment690147_563201) I can find here on Super User, is about downloads *failing* for digitally signed executables, not for others. (So if signatures would be related in your case, I'd assume that your problem would be limited to some specific executables too. Still then: your OS is old, and maybe so are the root certs?)

Comment: Curious... You've been having this problem for almost a year now?

Comment: @Arjan, Probably over 2 years. For files that I can't download I will either zip and email over from another machine or use WinWget. But of course these stopgap solutions don't fix the real problem.

Comment: This might sound weird, but do you have your IE updated? I do remember that this happened to me several times, but on Windows 98. I could theorize that the download never ends due to some TIME_WAIT stuff going on. Anything related to IE might also be causing the problem, so, checking through Internet Options might also work in your favor.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard, I don't use IE anymore because XP support for IE has been halted. Webbing with an older version of IE is an extreme security risk. But yes, my Chrome / FireFox / Opera / Safari are all of the latest versions.

Comment: I didn't ask that. Despite lack of support, IE needs to be updated, at least to the latest version. A [recent post](http://superuser.com/questions/749045/should-i-install-internet-explorer-updates-although-i-disabled-it) illustrates this. Also, since IE embeds itself with Windows, even if you don't use it, there are security settings inside that may prevent you from downloading the file.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard, Ok, this is my IE version: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dinwc.png . But I do think that browsers like Chrome and FireFox have their own *native* code doing the downloads which bypasses IE altogether.

Comment: OK, that's the latest version, but while your reasoning may be correct, IE still detains a lot of control over anything related to the Internet. By personal experience, if you place a website on Internet Options > Safety - Restricted Sites list, it will prevent Firefox from showing the page (after restart). At any rate, since you don't use IE, there is no perceivable harm done in at least investigating what options there may be that prevent your download from coming through. At the very least you can reset the settings to the default.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard, Yes investigation is good, ask anything, I'll provide the info.

Comment: Which directory are you downloading to? I remember having all kinds of problems in XP once the *full* path got longer than about 100 characters long...

Comment: @bdecaf, On Chrome, it downloads to `C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop`. I've tried downloading uTorrentStable http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/win but it doesn't work http://i.stack.imgur.com/JfP24.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/zfpTV.png. Then I changed the Chrome dl path to `C:\Dl`, but the same problem persists...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [lftp](http://ben.timby.com/pub/lftp-4.3.0.zip). You will get better diagnostic messages. However, **lftp** itself must be downloaded first, e.g. as a part of **cygwin** or from the above mentioned link (not an exe file!). That archive must be unpacked into some directory where lftp can be executed. Cygwin version includes lftpget:

```
lftpget -c http://example.com/JavaSetup7u21.exe
```

Bare-bones lftp command is a bit less obvious:

```
lftp.exe  --help
lftp.exe  -c get http://example.com/JavaSetup7u21.exe
```

### To answer your non-question

The Opera browser was playing similar tricks on me as in your case, aborting downloads. That was probably due to poorly configured or poorly working router that dropped packets. **Lftp** has superior reconnection abilities and would still download the files completely.

Comment: Doesn't work, it says "unknown command"....

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily disable your Anti-virus or/and  Anti-malware programs

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: While the OP has indeed indicated *they* do not have any anti virus installed (weird...), I still feel this answer might help others that have the same issue, @Doktoro. (And that's what Stack Exchange is about, right? A library of *generic* questions and answers?)

Comment: @Arjan I do agree with you, if this was a generic question. The phrase regarding the inexistence of a firewall or an antivirus suite can be understood as that the user has disabled the firewall/antivirus and yet it didn't work for him. As such, I felt this didn't answer this particular question when reviewing this.

Comment: The title is generic enough for me, @Doktoro. (Even more, with that many details in the question, I'd almost vote to close as being "too localized" but that's non-existing nowadays...)

Comment: @RMazi, Anti-virus would be the first thing anyone would check... but no I couldn't disable it because **I don't even have it** installed on this machine.

Comment: Have you checked disk? As in http://errordetail.com/2796/when-doing-downloads-they-stop-at-99%25-and-never-complete

Comment: @Pacerier, *"Anti-virus would be the first thing anyone would check"*, well, [some comments](http://superuser.com/questions/62370/downloads-stall-at-99-or-so/62372#comment64538_62372) prove otherwise.

Comment: @RMazi, Some files download fine with no problem so I don't think it's a disk error. What do you mean by "check disk"?

Comment: I mean disk health check http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/check-a-drive-for-errors Also there may be some errors in event viewer

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest you to use download manager & then report back if there are any problems.
You can try [this](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/download.htm).
Its free!

Secondly why are you downloading to temporary folder?
Try downloading to another folder.

Comment: He's most likely copying to a temporary folder because the download is for demonstration purposes only.  I can't see why a separate download manager rather than the one built into IE or Chrome would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe the user has no privileges to write executables on that temporary folder.

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz, I'm having full admin status.